# Can a mod_rewrite result in GET requests being ignored?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I am having trouble accessing my get request...

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /alex
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ admin/index.php?page=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(admin|assets|inventory|test)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(admin|assets|inventory|test)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
ErrorDocument 404 /alex/index.php?page=404
ErrorDocument 403 /alex/index.php?page=404
```

The URL I'm hitting:

> http://example.com/alex/admin/users?pagenum=37

Sample PHP code:

```
echo $_GET["pagenum"];
```

However, I am getting absolutely no get variable echo'ed out on my php. Is my .htaccess causing this? if not... What is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `QSA` flag in your rewrites:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /alex
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ admin/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(admin|assets|inventory|test)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(admin|assets|inventory|test)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The flag will append any existing query string to the end of the one that you've constructed in the rule's target. Normally, if you don't have a `?` in your rule's target, query strings get appended by default. But if you do have a `?` in your target, you need `QSA`.

Comment: @Pachonk it just stops the rewriting for the current iteration, there's no need to apply any of the remaining rules if you've already matched one of them

Comment: Okay! Thanks, I will be accepting this answer in 10 minutes. Sorry for a bit of user id10t error here.